# How to access an external element inside a polymerjs element

Tags: polymer

How to access an external element inside a polymerjs element.

```
<polymer-element attributes="externalDropZoneContainerId">>
<script>
    Polymer('file-upload', {
        ready: function(){
            //Here I want to access the externalDropZoneContainerId so that I can bind drag and drop functionality to this ID
            //$('#' + externalDropZoneContainerId) does not work.
        }
    })
</script>
<polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is accessible via `this.externalDropZoneContainerId`, the standard DOM API to get elements is [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```
<polymer-element attributes="externalDropZoneContainerId">>
<script>
    Polymer('file-upload', {
        ready: function(){
            var elem = document.getElementById(this.externalDropZoneContainerId);
        }
    })
</script>
<polymer-element>
```

Instead of the `ready` event you should maybe use the `domReady` event instead, otherwise the other element may not yet be guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Sorry about this. I did not test this as I found a work around not in this manner. I will test it soon and will update your answer